# Null Exception Java Applet In HTML

Tags: java, html, applet, nullpointerexception, japplet

Hi below is my java applet code. Its working fine as a standalone applet when run as applet. But when I embed it in the html page, I always get the NULL Exception error. I realized that when I take out the image things out, there is no problem displaying in HTML.

Why is it that the image is causing the null exception error?

```
public class SymmetryLine extends JApplet {

DrawingCanvas canvas = new DrawingCanvas();

JSlider slider1, slider2, slider3, slider4, slider5, slider6, slider7, slider8;

JPanel outerBig, top, down;
JLabel moveHorizontal, moveVertical, moveRotate;

  double transX = 0.0;

  double transY = 0.0;

  double rotateTheta = 0.0;

  double rotateX = 150.0;

  double rotateY = 150.0;

  double scaleX = 1.0;

  double scaleY = 1.0;

  float width = 1.0f;

  Image image;

  public SymmetryLine()
  {
      try {
         image = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("symmetry.jpg").toURI()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

public void init()
{

    outerBig=new JPanel();
    outerBig.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));


    top = new JPanel();
    top.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

    moveHorizontal = new JLabel("Move Right/Left:");
    moveVertical = new JLabel("Move Up/Down:");
    moveRotate = new JLabel("Rotate Line:");

    top.add(moveHorizontal);        
    slider1 = createSlider(top, JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 300, 150, 100, 50);

    top.add(moveVertical);      
    slider2 = createSlider(top, JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 300, 150, 100, 50);

    top.add(moveRotate);    
    slider3 = createSlider(top, JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 360, 0, 90, 45);


    outerBig.add(top);


    outerBig.add(canvas);

    getContentPane().add(outerBig);


}

public JSlider createSlider(JPanel panel, int orientation, int minimumValue, int maximumValue,
          int initValue, int majorTickSpacing, int minorTickSpacing) {
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(orientation, minimumValue, maximumValue, initValue);
        slider.setPaintTicks(true);
        slider.setMajorTickSpacing(majorTickSpacing);
        slider.setMinorTickSpacing(minorTickSpacing);
        slider.setPaintLabels(true);
        slider.addChangeListener(new SliderListener());
        panel.add(slider);
        return slider;
      }

class SliderListener implements ChangeListener {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      JSlider tempSlider = (JSlider) e.getSource();

      if (tempSlider.equals(slider1)) {
        transX = slider1.getValue() - 150.0;
        System.out.println("transX:" +slider1.getValue());

        canvas.repaint();
      } else if (tempSlider.equals(slider2)) {
        transY = slider2.getValue() - 150.0;
        System.out.println("transY:" + slider2.getValue());

        canvas.repaint();
      } else if (tempSlider.equals(slider3)) {
        rotateTheta = slider3.getValue() * Math.PI / 180;
        canvas.repaint();
      } 
    }
  }

class DrawingCanvas extends Canvas {
    public DrawingCanvas() {
      setSize(300, 300);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g); 


      g.drawImage(image, 100, 100, this);


      Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

      g2D.translate(transX, transY);
      g2D.rotate(rotateTheta, rotateX, rotateY);
      g2D.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
      BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(width);
      g2D.setStroke(stroke);
      Line2D line1 = new Line2D.Float(0f, 200f, 800f, 200f);
      g2D.draw(line1);



    }
  }

public Image getImage() throws IOException, URISyntaxException
{
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("symmetry.jpg").toURI()));

    return image;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the stack trace also.

Comment: @AnkitZalani hmm there is an error on applet in the webpage. "Errors":Click for details" ..So when I clicked, only the pop up came out showing NullPointerException

Comment: *"..there is an error on applet in the webpage"*  That output is in the Java Console.  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("symmetry.jpg").toURI()));
```

Should be

```
image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("symmetry.jpg"));
```

`ImageIO.read(..)` is overloaded to accept `ImageInputStream`, `InputStream`, `File` or `URL`.  Since some URLs cannot be formed into a valid `File`, stick with using the `URL`.